providing refer to?
What does the word “providing” in this sentence refer to? dermal papilla or blood capillaries ? logically it refers to both, but do we usually think in terms of the closest word?

The hair bulb is at the base of the follicle, with blood capillaries, known as dermal
papilla, providing nutrients to the hair cells.


"blood capillaries"  is the understood subject of providing. The blood capillaries provide nutrients to the hair cells.

It directly refers to "blood capillaries". "known as dermal papilla" is parenthetical, so it can be removed from the sentence without changing its essential meaning.

The hair bulb is at the base of the follicle, with blood capillaries providing nutrients to the hair cells.

The intent of the parenthetical can be achieved with a second sentence:

These capillaries are known as dermal papilla.


Well, both. The clause "known as dermal papilla" is a nonrestrictive clause mentioning what blood capillaries that serve this function are known as. In other words, those capillaries are dermal papilla. So there are blood capillaries that provide nutrients to the hair cells, and those blood capillaries are known as "dermal papilla".
